# how to get the desktop location of the user

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, path, subprocess

I am making a python script to merge a audio and video file through FFMPEG the code shown below is working perfectly fine but what i want to do is the (path) which i provided is of my desktop location but if somebody else will run this code then they will get error. so how can i give a universal path for desktop for any computer

```
import os
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
os.chdir('C://Users/ravir/desktop/') # how to get the users desktop location 
def merge():
  global p
  p =subprocess.Popen('ffmpeg -i video.avi -i audio.wav -c copy -shortest output.mkv' ,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)


rec_btn = tk.Button(text='Start merging', width=20, command=merge)
rec_btn.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
...  
os.chdir(f'C://Users/{os.getlogin()}/desktop/') # how to get the users desktop  
...
```

should work. os.getlogin() get's the username of the current logged on user and using the f-string will allow you to insert it into the pathname.

To expand on this a bit if you ever move this to a unix system you would want to use the pwd module

```
import pwd  

# will return the login name of the user who ran script and root if run with sudo
pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]
```

I guess a little clarification is in order here.  `os.getlogin()` as the name suggests gets the login name of the current user so in your case you would probably be able to run it like that on Windows and Unix.

`pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]` gets the user who **ran** the script, which is useful if you want to check if the script is run by root via `sudo`.

Note:  f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6 I think so if you are using an earlier version of python then you'd have to do something like:

```
username = os.getlogin()
os.chdir('C://Users/%s/desktop/' % username )
```

Comment: can you tell me how to hide the cmd window. as i don't want to show the cmd window to the user and run this process in background.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this but I believe if it is launched in the background it wouldn't generate a cmd window but I don't use Windows much for python development and if I do it is usually in a Docker container.